# Web app setup on Windows 2003 fails with error 1615

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-6, installation

I'm trying to install a .NET 3.5 web application I on a Win 2003 server with IIS6. The application installed fine a few versions ago and the old msi still works. As far as I know nothing has changed with the installer apart from a version number, one more dll in the application and the ProductCode of the setup project. However, the latest msi stops with the message:

> The installer was interrupted before <ApplicationName> could be
>   installed. You need to restart the installer to try again.

The log contains this error:

```
MSI (c) (B8:0C) [23:12:38:964]: Doing action: WEBCA_GatherAppPools
MSI (c) (B8:0C) [23:12:38:964]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 23:12:38: WEBCA_GatherAppPools.
MSI (c) (B8:0C) [23:12:38:964]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'WEBCA_GatherAppPools' 
MSI (c) (B8:88) [23:12:38:995]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\DOCUME~1\had012SA\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\MSIA0.tmp, Entrypoint: GatherAppPools
INFO   : [10/14/2011 23:12:39:042] [GatherAppPools                          ]: Custom Action is starting...
INFO   : [10/14/2011 23:12:39:042] [GatherAppPools                          ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
MSI (c) (B8!84) [23:12:39:042]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ComboBox 
MSI (c) (B8!84) [23:12:39:042]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: ComboBox 4: INSERT INTO `ComboBox` (`Property`,`Order`,`Value`,`Text`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) TEMPORARY 
ERROR  : [10/14/2011 23:12:39:042] [GatherAppPools                          ]: FAILED:  -2147023281
ERROR  : [10/14/2011 23:12:39:042] [GatherAppPools                          ]: Custom Action failed with code: '1615'
INFO   : [10/14/2011 23:12:39:042] [GatherAppPools                          ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '1615'
Action ended 23:12:39: WEBCA_GatherAppPools. Return value 3.
```

This [page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229683) says error 1615 is an SQL syntax error but the action is a standard MS action so I can't do much about. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I've tried creating a new web app in Visual Studio 2008 and a setup project for it and that installer does not work either so I suspect it's something with my Visual Studio. I can't think of what though so I still need help...

**UPDATE 2:** Curiouser and curiouser... a colleague compiled the code without making any changes and the installer works. Now the question becomes what has happened to my VS2008 and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

could be a change in the projects database structure.
Possibly you have a database with an older version of the Combobox table from previous versions. 
Try deleting the db before preforming a clean install of the application.

Comment: Check the documentation for the product, there is no direct reference in the log posted above.

Comment: The product as in the application? I've written that, there's no ComboBox table. That failing action, WEBCA_GatherAppPools, is a standard Visual Studio Setup Project action for filling a combobox with AppPools so my application database doesn't matter at that stage.